# How to get span text into input form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, class, input

Am trying to display the text in the span class into input form. I tried almost everything i can think of but nothing is giving good results.

Something like

Help please!
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVWbG.jpg)

Comment: [ask] Welcome to SO - Please read this when asking a question

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please post what you've already tried.

In Javascript, you can do it like this:

```
const inputField = document.getElementById(...);
const spanField = document.getElementById(...);
inputField.value = spanField.textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question;

```js
document.querySelector('.input').value = document.querySelector('.text').innerHTML
```

```html
<div>
<span class='text'>here is some text</span>
<input type='text' class='input' />

</div>
```

now where to put the javascript depends.

If you want to do it right after the window loads;

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
// here goes the javascript

})
```

If you want to do it on a button click;

```
document.getElementById('id_of_button').addEventListener('click', () => {

// here goes the javascript
})
```

Comment: Yes, thats what i really wanted, but now am not sure how and where i should put the javascript part, help please. (beginner here)

Comment: let me edit my answer. I will put the details there

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this before Asking a question with developers across the world. check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I'll recommend you to learn properly before working with those. You need to show what you have done.

However,
You can use PLACEHOLDER If you need to display a text in the input field.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <span class='text'>here is some text</span>
        <input type='text' class='input' />
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector('.input').value = document.querySelector('.text').innerHTML
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This might Fix your Problem Now!
See The JavaScript Approach [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_JavaScript_within_a_webpage)